# Bitwise and logical operators

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I just discovered bitwise (&,|,^,~) operators. I known logical (&&,||) operators for some time and I have many ideas of there uses.

After checking out on internet, I have understand how they work, but I haven't seen any practical exemple to these.

What the point to make operations on a bit level ?

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts

Kenshin

EDIT : I'm sorry It's seems I haven't been precise enough in my question. I just wan't practical use for bitwise operators since I haven't had to use them in any of my C++ projects and I haven't been enable to find example on where it is used.

Thanks again

Comment: You have to keep trying to understand them (at least the logical ones) because they are really essential in all programming languages, so if you do not understand them, then you will never become a programmer or a computer scientist in general.

Comment: It's not so important to understand immediately what the bitwise operators are, unlike you are working with bits and bytes, which is not the case probably..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, bitwise arithmetic is used when accessing status bits from a hardware register or for extracting bits from an unsigned integer.

Search StackOverflow for "c++ bit twiddling example".

**Edit 1: Example - Reading UART status**

```
#define CHAR_RECEIVED (0x02)
  uint32_t volatile * const UART_STATUS_REGISTER = (uint32_t volatile * )0xFFFFD000;
  volatile uint32_t status = *UART_STATUS_REGISTER;
  while ((status & CHAR_RECEIVED) == 0)
  {
    status = *UART_STATUS_REGISTER;
  }
```